# SSRS on database server trying to get production server SSL access

Tags: database, server, reporting

I have Sql Server Enterprise Edition and I have it on my database server utilizing Reporting services. On Reporting services configuration Manager, I cant get any access to our sites SSL. Is there a way I can do so without downloading IIS on my database server or if I can access a different server in configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012 or 2014? I think you can configure the ssl url of reports and reportserver in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.